# Streaming Audio Via SSH to an Android Device

Tags: android, command-line, android-ndk

I'm able to securely stream audio from one PC to another via SSH using:

```
ssh <username>@<host> 'dd bs=1k if=/dev/audio' > /dev/audio
```

Is there any similar way to do this from a terminal running on an Android phone? I tried testing this from a terminal emulator running on a Droid X, but the standard "/dev/audio" device is missing.

Note, I realize this could probably be accomplished by writing a custom app, but I'd like to avoid that overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be to install a streaming server (i.e. icecast) on the Linux box and connect to it from your Android using any Internet Radio Client.

IIRC, icecast support authentication and SSL.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this. By default android phones do not run SSH, nor do they have /dev/audio available (I'm actually uncertain where the audio path on most android devices terminates).

I see a custom app in your future.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to say "there is no way..." It might be that "the Design of the Android excludes ..." I have just spent the afternoon getting ssh to work, there are apps in teh app store to act as ssh clients and I've just written a test app to do ssh programmatically.It might well be that you cannot get it working but that does not men "no way"

Comment: SSH is the easy part.  But there is no readily apparent direct way to do audio output from a command line executable running as an ordinary userid - you lack the permission to do it directly, and you lack registration through binder with the android platform since you do not inherit it from zygote as an app's process would.  The audio would probably have to be proxied through an Android style Service using some linux IPC mechanism, and from there to the system audio stack which has the permission (and knowledge) to access the audio device driver itself.